# How to convert datatypes?

Tags: errors, strings, floating-point

I am trying to use datatools `\DTLfetch` to grab a real number from a database loaded from a .csv file, and then pass this numeric argument to `\FPeval`.

Problem is that `\DTLfetch` always seems to return a string instead of a numeric, which gives an error because FP can't handle string datatypes.

`\DTLgetvalue` always returns the desired numeric datatype and everything works, however, I really need `\DTLfetch`.

I have spent the last two days trying to figure out how to convert a string to a numeric datatype in LaTeX, or alternatively, how to get `\DTLfetch` to return a numeric value instead of a string.

Is LaTeX seriously deficient in this capability? or am I missing something fundamental? Should I use Sagetex to do the conversion?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 5):

TeX is a macro language, it does not have any other types than strings. (There are typed registers, but they are not relevant here)
The problem is not that `\DTLfetch` "returns" a string, it is that `\DTLfetch` is not expandable.

Non-expandable macros like `\DTLfetch` do not expand to a value, but sometimes they insert some results in the current list. That is why you can use see the result from `DTLfetch` in your document, but it does not work inside `\FPeval`.

To fix this, you can use a variant `\DTLfetchsave` of `\DTLfetch` which egreg has written for [retrieving substring of `\DTLfetch`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/335483/retrieving-substring-of-dtlfetch). It saves the result in a new macro, which can then be expanded (similar to `\FPeval` itself):

```
\begin{filecontents*}{students.csv}
name,grade
Joe Bloggs,2.7
Jane Doe,1.0
John Smith,3.0
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool,fp}

% From egreg at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/335483/retrieving-substring-of-dtlfetch
\newcommand{\DTLfetchsave}[5]{%
  \edtlgetrowforvalue{#2}{\dtlcolumnindex{#2}{#3}}{#4}%
  \dtlgetentryfromcurrentrow{\dtlcurrentvalue}{\dtlcolumnindex{#2}{#5}}%
  \let#1\dtlcurrentvalue
}

\begin{document}
  \DTLloaddb{students}{students.csv}
  \DTLfetchsave\grade{students}{name}{Jane Doe}{grade}
  \FPeval\doublegrade{2*\grade}
  \doublegrade
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when trying to use data from a (CSV) database for plotting single values with TikZ/PGFPlots or for printing values using siunitx.

With [this](https://www.mrunix.de/forums/showthread.php?77183-Datatool-gt-Zellen-auslesen-und-Variablen-zuweisen) post I found out how to store all values from the database as (expanded) LaTeX variable named after the respective key:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{mydb.csv}
key;value
mykey;1.0
\end{filecontents*}

% Relevant code below
\usepackage{datatool}
\DTLsetseparator{;}
\DTLloaddb{mydb}{mydb.csv}

\begin{document}
\DTLforeach{mydb}{\Key=key,\Value=value}
{%
   \cslet{\Key}{\Value}%
}
\DTLfetch{mydb}{key}{mykey}{value} works\\
% while $\num{\DTLfetch{mydb}{key}{mykey}{value}}$ fails
\mykey prints the value for mykey, $\num{\mykey}$ also works
\end{document}
```

However, loading multiple databases with similar keys would re-assign the same variables.

As a quick fix, I made `DTLFetch` assign the values to variables named after a concatenation of database name and key and wrote a function to parse the latter:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{mydb.csv}
key;value
mykey;1.0
\end{filecontents*}

% Relevant code below
\usepackage{datatool}
\DTLsetseparator{;}
\DTLloaddb{mydb}{mydb.csv}

\newcommand{\getval}[2]{\csname#1#2\endcsname}

\begin{document}
\DTLforeach{mydb}{\Key=key,\Value=value}
{%
   \cslet{mydb\Key}{\Value}%
}
\getval{mydb}{mykey} prints the value for mykey, $\num{\getval{mydb}{mykey}}$ also works
\end{document}
```

Answer (score -1):

I also discovered 
`\xDTLassignfirstmatch` in `datatool` that seems to work the same as `\DTLfetch`, with expansion, and works great for me!

Comment: Please provide details of how to use this and give an example.

Comment: I found the basis for my solution here: [https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/178904/use-datatool-to-read-a-row-from-a-csv-file-then-use-the-variables-in-the-docume]. '\xDTLassignfirstmatch' is like '\DTLassignfirstmatch' but performs a one-level expansion on {value} which is also something I needed. eg: '\xDTLassignfirstmatch{dbname}{col_key}{value}{assign_list}'

Comment: Is someone assigned to add information to datatool documentation on CTAN? It would have been great to know which macros are expandable, and which aren't.