# Automatic export of different PDF versions from LaTeX based on a spreadsheet

Tags: pdftex

I am a teacher designing short quizzes for students. My students take a quiz and from that I create a spreadsheet with their answers. Depending on whether they give a correct or false answer I want to omit or reuse that question in the upcoming quiz, respectively.

Can I feed LaTeX the spreadsheet and let it compile separate PDF documents containing questions that they answered false in the previous quiz? How would you go about doing this?

1 row in my spreadsheet equals to 1 student with their answers.
I'm saving each question as a separate `.tex` file.

Comment: do you have a Minimal Working Example to show?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301). Yes, I am pretty sure you can accomplish what you desire. However, you are basically asking two different and unrelated questions here: 1. Can LaTeX read a CSV file and determine a true/false condition (assuming you can generate a CSV file)? 2. How do I use a conditional typesetting.  The specifics will depend a on exactly how you are doing things and want to control the various aspects, so having more details would be helpful.

Comment: There are numerous questions on this site related to those two. For 1 you could start with [Use datatool to read a row from a CSV file, then use the variables in the document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/178904/4301) and for 2 there is [Conditional typesetting / build](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33576/4301). I would recommend you start with those and post a more specific question if you get stuck. Or, you those to construct a  [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) that sets up the problem and edit the question to include that.

Comment: If you use Linux, before of reinvent the wheel you should check what AMC (auto-multiple-choice) does  (more of what you are asking)  including export statistics by student and by questions  to a OpenOffice spreadsheet. This part however is not made by Latex (that make only the exam sheets) but by a GUI. It is available in most used Debian-based distros, so install and try is the easy part (the hard part is understand their own macros and environments, but reading the fine manual, is not so hard).